# How to attach domain name to my server?

Tags: linux

I have a small problem, looked here & other forums, but could not find solution.
I have site at my-domain.com, site is on shared host. In my domain register I added DNS servers which hosting provider gave to me when I opened hosting account for my-domain.com and all that works for 1 year. Since traffic to site increased, hosting company told me to move my site to vps or dedicated server on their hosts or some other hosts, so I found good offer on another provider and bught 1 vps with tech specs that I need with ubuntu 10.10.

On the other side, I makde on my computer ubunutu 10.10 installation and rewrited application for better performance (web server/mail server/database etc...) When I make backup on my home machine, and upload and extract on remote VPS everything is as it should be, but I ma testing using VPS IP address, site that users and search engines access is on old shared hosting still.

Now I want to add new remote vps IP to my domain register NAME servers, but I don't know:

-should I add my VPS ip?
-in that case what be my secondary name server?
-what I need to do on my remote VPS with complete site(app) to edit so it can be accessible to my-domain.com?is that hostname, or what?

I hope that You understand what is problem, and I am sure that this is something simple for people who are doing with those stuffs,so please help me.Thanks

Comment: I m not gonna down vote this question but i think you should ask this question on other stackexchange site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to explain, you have multiple things here:

- Domain name
- DNS nameservers
- Web server(s)

All of these can be hosted with separate providers, but depending on your provider you might have different management options.

## Domain name

Your domain name has a registrar (who you bought it from). That registrar will keep a list of 1-3 'nameservers' which are the addresses for the provider that hosts your DNS.

## DNS nameservers

Your DNS is like your address book. That needs to be hosted somewhere, and if your old host didn't let you edit it, it's probably just part of their shared hosting service, and not something you can manage. You will need to change your domain name to point to another set of nameservers at a provider you can manage. Your VPS provider probably has a DNS service, but possibly not free (although many are). If needed you can use a free DNS host like [XName](http://www.xname.org/) or [ClouDNS](http://www.cloudns.net/), but depending on your level of knowledge you might find these difficult to use.

A basic web server record you will want to add is known as an `A` record, and will point `my-domain.com.` and/or `www.my-domain.com.` (using a separate record) to your web server's IP address.

## Web server

Your server has an IP address. If you need to load-balance for performance reasons you'll need your hosting company to provide you a 'virtual IP' or a load-balancer service, behind which you can have multiple servers.

## Summary

The way the request goes is:

1. User types my-domain.com into their browser
2. The user's ISP's DNS server is queried for my-domain.com
3. The web server IP address for my-domain.com is returned
4. The user's browser sends a HTTP GET request to your server to get the web page

One part of the process leads onto the next, so you need to make the 3 things work in harmony to get your site to function.

Comment: dsample thanks for this very useful info. But those facts are just general, and I read them and know them 'in theory'. Situation that I have is that on that VPS is ONLY 1 website, so I need no virtual servers etc. And I want to in my domain register put DNS record that point to this VPS, and only site is default apache instalation at var/www to be visible to user after all this process(dns resolving,browser request,etc...) My question is what i need to do with my VPS, do I need DNS to install or every browser request will be resolved since it goes to default apache web dir?

Comment: You'll still need everything in the chain... the DNS records hosted somewhere, and pointing that A record to your VPS's IP address, as well as the domain's registrar pointing your domain towards that DNS host's servers.  There's no way to just connect the domain directly to the VPS. All your VPS needs to do is respond to requests for my-domain.com and/or www.my-domain.com, and as long as the DNS is set up correctly the site should work.