# python Falcon changing domain name for Request URL

Tags: python, api, falconframework

For an API I am writing in Falcon (python) I am trying to have the API hosted on a different domain name than localhost:8080. I want to be able to request at http://mydomainname rather than http://localhost:8080. How do I set up my API to do that when using Falcon to develop my API. Let me know if you can help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a WSGI/ASGI Python application framework, Falcon does not have much control of how your server is reached by domain name.

Your server IP address is normally resolved by a DNS nameserver, so "hosting on a domain" is essentially making sure that (1) an application server is bound to 1 or more IP addresses, and (2) DNS queries resolve the domain name in question to these IP address(es). See also, e.g., [How to attach domain name to my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753148/how-to-attach-domain-name-to-my-server)

That said, an HTTP 1.1+ request normally does include the domain name via the HTTP Host header; a Falcon application can access this information via [`Request.host`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.host), [`Request.uri`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.uri), etc. If you expect your application being accessed with different `Host` header values, you can use these `Request` properties to differentiate between different domains.